# Should I use the navigation schema on faceted navigation and footer navigation?

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

I am in the process of updating the structured data on my site and added the siteNavigationElement schema to top category navigation on my page.

I was wondering if it is beneficial or if it is incorrect to add this schema to the faceted navigation and the navigation in the footer.

Comment: Do you mean [`SiteNavigationElement`](http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement)?

Comment: Yep I do, Should this just be for the main navigation?

Comment: What do you mean by "beneficial"?   There is absolutely no benefit to using most schema on your website.   There are only a few limited cases like markup for user reviews where you get some benefit in the form of stars in the search results from Google.